# Google Sheet: break transpose to the next row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Beginning from the date on the right corner of the table, I need to automatically fill the days of the calendar.

Is it possible to transpose until a given cell and break it to the next row?

|  |  |  |  |  | 2/2/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sun | mon | tue | wed | thu | fri |
|  |  | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | ... |  |

```
=Arrayformula ( Transpose( AND WHAT?)
```

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: no.  are you trying to "unpivot" data?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: I have no clue how to start it

Comment: I suggest that you include a link to the destination spreadsheet showing what is happening *now* with the IMPORTRANGE and, in another sheet of the same spreadsheet, a clear example of what you *want* that data to look like.